# Why am I getting an error while installing discord.py on mac

Tags: python, macos, discord.py

**QUICK NOTE:** This question is probably more related to `macos` or `zsh` than python.

I am trying to install `discord.py` on macos monterey, though I have the `xcode command line tools`, I am facing errors while installing `discord.py`. I am running `Python 3.11.0a5`.

The whole output:

```sh
Collecting discord.py
  Using cached discord.py-1.7.3-py3-none-any.whl (786 kB)
Collecting aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0
  Using cached aiohttp-3.7.4.post0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting yarl<2.0,>=1.0
  Using cached yarl-1.7.2.tar.gz (168 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0
  Using cached async_timeout-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
Collecting chardet<5.0,>=2.0
  Using cached chardet-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (178 kB)
Collecting typing-extensions>=3.6.5
  Using cached typing_extensions-4.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting multidict<7.0,>=4.5
  Using cached multidict-6.0.2-cp311-cp311-macosx_10_9_universal2.whl
Collecting attrs>=17.3.0
  Using cached attrs-21.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
Collecting idna>=2.0
  Using cached idna-3.3-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: yarl
  Building wheel for yarl (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for yarl (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [43 lines of output]
      **********************
      * Accelerated build *
      **********************
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/yarl
      copying yarl/_url.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/yarl
      copying yarl/_quoting_py.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/yarl
      copying yarl/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/yarl
      copying yarl/_quoting.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/yarl
      running egg_info
      writing yarl.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to yarl.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to yarl.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to yarl.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'yarl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.cache' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl/*.html'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl/*.so'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl/*.pyd'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'yarl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      copying yarl/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/yarl
      copying yarl/_quoting_c.c -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/yarl
      copying yarl/_quoting_c.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/yarl
      copying yarl/_quoting_c.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/yarl
      copying yarl/py.typed -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/yarl
      running build_ext
      building 'yarl._quoting_c' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/yarl
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11 -c yarl/_quoting_c.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/yarl/_quoting_c.o
      yarl/_quoting_c.c:198:12: fatal error: 'longintrepr.h' file not found
        #include "longintrepr.h"
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
Failed to build yarl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for yarl, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to install `yarl` because some dependency it needed to build it for you failed… you may not need to pre install it, but if you tried you would know what was missing for the build.

Comment: @Jarvis but even when I try to install `yarl`, the same error shows up.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://github.com/aio-libs/yarl#installation) of `yarl` you need a `c` compiler and Python headers installed. It also mentions a non-compiled version, but it is slow. I would try to install the compiler and Python headers.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3.11/whatsnew/3.11.html#whatsnew311-c-api-porting

You're getting an error because you're using an alpha release of Python 3.11 and YARL hasn't been updated to support it yet.

```
The non-limited API files cellobject.h, classobject.h, code.h, context.h, funcobject.h, genobject.h and longintrepr.h have been moved to the Include/cpython directory. Moreover, the eval.h header file was removed. These files must not be included directly, as they are already included in Python.h: Include Files. If they have been included directly, consider including Python.h instead. (Contributed by Victor Stinner in bpo-35134.)
```

You should use a supported version of Python 3.10.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading it:

pip install -U yarl